# Window 7 all applications non-responsive

Tags: windows-7

Yesterday during regular use of my Windows 7 computer, all my open programs stopped responding. I could move the mouse and saw ui responses when I hovered over windows, but if I tried to close a window or click something, nothing would happen. The start menu wouldn't open either. Since the computer was stuck like this, I had to restart by holding the power button. I restarted and ran chkdsk and everything seemed fine. Unfortunately, I woke up to the same problem this morning and once again, chkdsk fixed it for now. I imagine it's going to happen again.

How can I debug what's going on? It seems like some sort of deadlocking.

Comment: Information on what chkdsk did exactly would be helpful.  It sounds like you should replace your HDD though.

Comment: @Ramhound, it would run on system restart and then reboot after, so I haven't seen the output

Comment: Since you can't tell us what chkdsk ended up doing.  Can you share information on the health of the drive?  This is a classic sign of a bad HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have two drives. The primary is an SSD I bought less than a year ago and the other is a regular hard drive. Do you recommend any tools for testing them?

Comment: There are existing questions with existing answers on how to test the performance of a HDDs and/or SSDs

Comment: Note that what you are describing is Explorer.exe hanging. Since it is the window manager, it can certianly make all your windows freeze. Check your evenlog for the time of the issue, and see if you see any crash messages that may help in diagnosing the issue,

Comment: @FrankThomas, I think it's more than that though. I wasn't able to do things like pause iTunes or end processes through task manager (explorer included)

Comment: Be that as it may, my advice remains the same. check your eventlog, your system integrity (sfc.exe), RAM (Memtestx86 and the windows mem diag tools), and HDD (SMART stats, chkdsk, spinright)as others have suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I use a program called Spinrite from Gibson Research. Its strictly a hard drive scanning tool. It scans your hard drive for defects and if it finds data on a bad area, it moves it to a clean area of the drive. It a great tool for any network engineer to have.

I would also suggest performing a "scannow /sfc" from the run box. This performs an integrity check on all protected system files and corrects them.

Comment: You mean `sfc /scannow`? That didn't find anything

Comment: Yes, my bad. Here are some other ideas:

Comment: Try running hardware diagnostics and try re-seating memory modules.